# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para eliminar los datos de mi otra tabla?

Tags: php, html, mysql, base-de-datos

Saludos agredeceria su ayuda en este caso. Sucede que tengo este codigo, el cual uso para consultar datos de dos tablas con un INNER JOIN y mostrar una tabla completa en pantalla, hasta alli me funciona perfecto. Luego agregue un boton de borrar en la ultima columna de mi tabla, me funciona perfectamente para eliminar los registros de mi tabla t1, pero necesito una manera de hacer que elimino los registros de mi tabla t2 con el mismo boton y funcion. Gracias de antemano.

Aca esta mi index.php:

```
<div class="container">
 <h4 class="mt-5">Indique el auxiliar que desea consultar</h4>
 <hr>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
<!-- Contenido -->   

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">
<form method="GET">
  <div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
      <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput">registro</label>
      <input name="registro" type="text" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" placeholder="Indique el numero de registro">  
      <input name="buscar" type="hidden" class="form-control mb-2" id="inlineFormInput" value="v">
    </div>
   
    <div class="col-auto">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Buscar Ahora</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
  </li>

</ul>
<br>
<?php
include('conexion.php');


if(isset($_GET["registro"])){
$pbu=$_GET["registro"]; 
    }
    
if(isset($_GET["buscar"])){                  
$sqln=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT t1.ITEM,t1.UBICACION,t1.N_DE_FIANZA, t1.NOMBRE_DE_AUXILIAR,t1.TIPO_DE_AUXILIAR,t1.N_DE_REGISTRO,t1.TIPO_DE_FIANZA,t1.FECHA_DE_OTORGAMIENTO,t1.MONTO_Bs,t1.DESDE,t1.HASTA,t1.ESTATUS,t1.ASEGURADORA
 ,t1.TECNICO_ANALISTA,t1.N_DE_OFICIO,t1.FECHA,t1.MONTO__Bs,t1.OBSERVACIONES,t1.REVISION,t2.N_DE_ANEXO,t2.DESDE_,t2.HASTA_,t2.MONTO_BS FROM auxiliares t1 INNER JOIN  anexos_auxiliares t2 ON t1.N_DE_FIANZA=t2.N_FIANZA WHERE t2.N_REGISTRO LIKE '%$pbu%' order by t1.ITEM") /*or die(mysqli_error())*/;
}
?>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    
  <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th COLSPAN=3  class="text-center">AUXILIAR</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan=3 class="text-center">VIGENCIA</th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan=4 class="text-center">ANEXOS</th>
        <th></th>
        <th colspan=4 class="text-center">FINIQUITO</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        </tr>
  
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ITEM</th>
      <th scope="col">UBICACION</th>
      <th scope="col">NOMBRE DE AUXILIAR</th>
      <th scope="col">TIPO DE AUXILIAR</th>
      <th scope="col">NUMERO DE REGISTRO</th>
      <th scope="col">NUMERO DE FIANZA</th>
      <th scope="col">TIPO DE FIANZA</th>
      <th scope="col">FECHA DE OTORGAMIENTO</th>
      <th scope="col">MONTO</th>
      <th scope="col">DESDE</th>
      <th scope="col">HASTA</th>
      <th scope="col">ESTATUS</th>
      <th scope="col">ASEGURADORA</th>
      <th scope="col">NUMERO DE ANEXO</th>
      <th scope="col">DESDE</th>
      <th scope="col">HASTA</th>
      <th scope="col">MONTO</th>
      <th scope="col">TECNICO ANALISTA</th>
            <th scope="col">NUMERO DE OFICIO</th>
      <th scope="col">FECHA</th>
            <th scope="col">MONTO (BS.)</th>
            <th scope="col">OBSERVACIONES</th>
      <th scope="col">REVISION</th>
      <th scope="col">OPCION</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>

<?php
if(isset($_GET["buscar"])){ 
while ($dato=mysqli_fetch_array($sqln))
{   


echo"<tbody>";
echo"<tr>";?>
<?php
echo"<td>".$dato['ITEM']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$dato['UBICACION']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['NOMBRE_DE_AUXILIAR']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['TIPO_DE_AUXILIAR']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['N_DE_REGISTRO']."</td>";
 echo"<td>".$dato['N_DE_FIANZA']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['TIPO_DE_FIANZA']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['FECHA_DE_OTORGAMIENTO']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['MONTO_Bs']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['DESDE']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['HASTA']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['ESTATUS']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['ASEGURADORA']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['N_DE_ANEXO']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['DESDE_']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['HASTA_']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['MONTO_BS']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['TECNICO_ANALISTA']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['N_DE_OFICIO']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['FECHA']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['MONTO__Bs']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['OBSERVACIONES']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$dato['REVISION']."</td>";
echo '<td><a href="eliminar.php?ITEM='.$dato['ITEM'].'" class="btn btn-danger">eliminar</a><td>';


echo"</tr>";
echo"  </tbody>";
}
}
?>

</table>
</div>
</form>
```

eliminar.php

```
<?php
 include('conexion.php');
 
 $id=$_GET['ITEM'];
 $sql="delete from auxiliares where ITEM='$id'";

 $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el otro `DELETE` usará el mismo valor, sería tan simple como agregar tu otra consulta `DELETE` y ejecutarla, algo así:

```
<?php  
    $id=$_GET['ITEM'] ?? null;
    if( isset($id) ) {
        include('conexion.php');

        $sql="delete from auxiliares where ITEM='$id'";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $sql="delete from laOtraTabla where laColumna='$id'";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        header('Location: index.php');

    } else {
        echo "No hay un id válido";
        #Pon el location de error o lo que quieras
    }
?>
```

Si el `where` debe provenir de otro valor, entonces pasa ese otro valor cuando llames a `eliminar.ph`.

Para ello cambia la línea del botón, usaré `printf` para ser más claro, esa mezcla de HTML / PHP me da verdadera alergia visual:

```
printf('<td><a href="eliminar.php?ITEM=%s&OTRODATO=%s" class="btn btn-danger">eliminar</a><td>',$dato['ITEM'],$aquiValorDelOtroDato);
```

Estaríamos pasando dos valores, el que ya tenías, con la clave `ITEM` y el otro dato con la clave `OTRODATO`, en el `printf`, al final, verás que he puesto una variable imaginaria `$aquiValorDelOtroDato`, debes cambiarla por el elemento o variable que contendría ese otro dato, donde quiera que esté.

Ahora el código quedaría así:

```
<?php  
    $id=$_GET['ITEM'] ?? null;
    $otroDato=$_GET['OTRODATO'] ?? null;

    if( isset($id) && isset($otroDato) ) {
        include('conexion.php');

        $sql="delete from auxiliares where ITEM='$id'";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $sql="delete from laOtraTabla where laColumna='$otroDato'";
        mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        header('Location: index.php');

    } else {
        echo "No hay un id válido";
        #Pon el location de error o lo que quieras
    }
?>
```

Cabe decir que tu forma de ejecutar esas consultas es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera muy seriamente implementar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese gravísimo riesgo de seguridad, aunque se trate de una base de datos de prueba.

Si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios al pie de esta respuesta. **Soy humano, no soy una IA**.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono el segundo codigo que colocaste, ya que, efectivamente necesitaba un dato distinto para cada tabla. Y sobre la vulnerabilidad, me sirve de esta forma ya que hasta ahora solo va a ser implementado en una red local.

Comment: @Josebas aunque sea una red local, pueden ocurrir cosas como que otro usuario de esa red con ciertas habilidades pueda escalar privilegios de acceso. O, esa red, por alguna vulnerabilidad, podría ser accedida desde el exterior. Además, las consultas preparadas son más rápidas, por lo general.

Answer (score 1):

La unión entre ambas tablas es el **Numero de Fianza** basado en `FROM auxiliares t1 INNER JOIN  anexos_auxiliares t2 ON t1.N_DE_FIANZA=t2.N_FIANZA`

Lo que primero me hace razonar, El numero de fianza es único? si es así puedes borrar de ambas tablas por ese numero de fianza, o al menos de la segunda.

Pseudocódigo

```
<?php
 include('conexion.php');
 
 $id=$_GET['ITEM'];
 $sqlFianza = "SELECT N_DE_FIANZA FROM auxiliares comoSeaQueSeLlameTuCampo = '$id' ";
 $sql="delete from auxiliares where ITEM='$id'";
 $sql2="delete from anexos_auxiliares where N_FIANZA = '$sqlFianza' ";
```

Esa sería como que la forma más fácil, otra puede ser que desde un inicio obtengas los ID's de ambas tablas y hagas un DELETE por esos ID's.

Poniéndolo de forma nada extravagante ni complicada.